# use a function in action of auth modules in wizard module in vuex in vue

Tags: vue.js, module, vuex, action, dispatch

I have this function in auth.module.js:

```
  async [VERIFY_AUTH](context) {
if (JwtService.getToken()) {
  ApiService.setTokenAxios();
  return (
    ApiService.get("api/customer/me")
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log("auth request - useer:", data);
        context.commit(SET_AUTH, data);
      })
      ///////////
      .catch(({ response }) => {
        console.log(response);
        context.commit(SET_ERROR, serviceErrors(response.data));
      })
  );
} else {
  context.commit(PURGE_AUTH);
}
```

},

I want dispatch it in wizard.modules.js

```
  [SPOUSES](context, data) {
console.log(data);
return new Promise(() => {
  ApiService.post(`api/customer/${data.id}/spouses`, data.form).then(
    ({ data }) => {
      console.log(data);

      context.dispatch("auth/VERIFY_AUTH", null, { root: true });
    }
  );
});
```

},

I try it but it dont work
do you know what should I do?

Comment: What exactly does not work? `new Promise` - this is promise construction antipattern. Never use it when there's already a promise. You create a promise that never resolves.

Comment: yes you righr
i remove new promis
already it dont work at all

Comment: This isn't shown in the question. It's unknown if you did this correctly. Again, what does not work? The question lacks clear problem statement, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask